# How to replace string inside MySQL field/column?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a shell script to launch SQL query, works fine.
I would like to replace, inside MySQL database, a specific code, which is different depending of the website.
See image below :

[image]

My query is the following :

```
mysql -D DATABASE_NAME -e "UPDATE TABLE SET params = REPLACE(params, '%OLD_CODE%', 'NEW_CODE') WHERE element = 'EXTENSION'"
```

The problem is : the% OLD_CODE% zone does not work. I have to enter the exact string.

Below the content of PARAMS field from MySQL database :

```
{"com_difficulty":"3","clubcode":"OLD_CODE","shownews":"1","com_calViewName":"flat","darktemplate":"0"}
```

I need to replace **OLD_CODE** by a **NEW_CODE**, without loosing settings inside **PARAMS** field.

Problem, since **OLD_CODE** string is different for each site, how to replace each **OLD_CODE** string ?

I have laso tried with * caracter to take everything but does not work.

Example:

how to replace this

```
{"com_difficulty":"3","clubcode":"546465-595gfd-gfgfds65-5654gfd","shownews":"1","com_calViewName":"flat","darktemplate":"0"}
```

by this :

```
{"com_difficulty":"3","clubcode":"fg5gfdgfq-grefdg-gredfgfd","shownews":"1","com_calViewName":"flat","darktemplate":"0"}
```

Thanks
L.

Comment: Why are you posting an illegible csv screen dump?. - please add sample data from the db as text.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain this `OLD_CODE` and *exact string* requirement in more detail.  And, @P.Salmon is right, your screen image is almost impossible to read.

Comment: Why do you add percent chars to string to be searched and replaced? REPLACE and LIKE even looks differently...

Comment: OK done, I ahve edited 1st post with more details. Hope this is good.

Comment: @Akina : was just to test. but not good apparently.

Comment: example added in post #1

Comment: So json stored as text where you want to replace the value of the of the pair clubcode:something.

Comment: @P.Salmon yes exactly.

Comment: any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this query works :

```
mysql -D DATABASE_NAME -e "UPDATE TABLE SET params = REGEXP_REPLACE(params, '\"clubcode\":\".+?\"', '\"clubcode\":\"TOTO\"') WHERE element = 'EXTENSION'"
```